# Angular - assets images accessable only on localhost

Tags: angular

I'm having issue displaying images at my application.

All svg files are in src/assets/images

angular.json

```
 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/webfonts"
            ],
```

localhost:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/assets/images/image.svg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
```

server:

```
Request URL: https://xxx.xxx.com/assets/images/image.svg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404
```

When I'm trying to access them on localhost everything is working. When I deploy the application to the server I get an error 404 under every image.

I don't undestand, how it's possible to work on localhost but not when it's build on a server.

I have some idea that `ng serve` which I'm using on localhost do something more (includes assets?) than `npm run build` which I'm using on a server

Comment: You need configure your web server on your server to grant access anyone to the /assets folder

Comment: Show your webserver config

Comment: I solved the problem moving images folder from assets to /src. Tbh I don't know why it's working this way :)